# How do I extract metadata or schema from geospatial database

Tags: rest, jdbc

How can I programmatically develop a method to extract metadata and schema from a geospatial database and write it to a metadata catalog. The extraction will be via a REST API (Both the geospatial database and the metadata catalog have REST APIs) or a custom JDBC connector that will need to be created. I do not know what metadata and schema are available via the API. Any metadata or schema that doesn't come over via API must be extracted via JDBC or other methods. The goal is to create an enduring connection between the geospatial database and the metadata catalog so that the catalog is always updated if the metadata or schema of the geospatial database changes.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Usually public APIs are versioned, so your code will work even if a new version is released. You need to check only if  there is a new version available and check if your code is compatible with it or you need to update it. As of the metadata extraction it depends on what kind of standards are used by the APIs or if there are standards used at all. For example RDF can be used to describe such metadata and public vocabs like schema.org, but in most cases many REST constraints are violated and the most you can do is reading the documentation instead of automatically extracting metadata.